# latest php version show bit field 18 digits

Tags: php

I have table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `notes` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `tf`  BIT(1),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When showing values from table, instead of bit value I have 18 digits.
What happens !?

This problem only occurs with php 7.1.1.
Runs properly with other versions (5.x, 7.0.x, 7.1.0)

Comment: Just in case its relevant, what version of MYSQL are you using?

Comment: And what database engine are you using?

Comment: I tested with mysql5,6,7 and mariadb5

Comment: Can you give an example of setting this column and reading it

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-type.html

Comment: I don't like this solution, but is only one: 
`SELECT name, BIN(tf + 0) AS tf FROM notes`
Thanks RiggsFolly

Comment: I dont have mysql5.6.7 but I dont get what you are saying you get, using PHP7.1.1